# Cannot type in textfields in IE11

Tags: internet-explorer, twitter-bootstrap, textfield

In my site, I cannot type in textboxes on IE11 on Windows 7. Clicking the text input field, I can see the caret blinking outside the field, positioned in another place in the page.
I can reproduce the problem across many computers with IE11.

Setting IE8 via Inspector solves the problem, with IE >= 9 it shows the problem.
The site uses Twitter Bootstrap.
I tried z-index fixes without success.

Site link: http://fortis7.moutheme.com/

Comment: I''m having this same issue.. it's so weird. unhooked all events.. same issue

Comment: I still having this issue in IE11. Sometime it works but most of times when i click on textfields my caret blinking outside the field, positioned in random place in the page. Please let me know if anyone knows any issue. I am not getting idea whether this is IE issue or my application. I am using jsf1.2/richface3.2.

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?

Answer (score 5):

I managed to fix this issue by giving it a `height`.

Comment: @UriAgassi This is a valid answer, as far as SO policies are concerned. There is no minimum post length requirement. It may not be a good or correct answer (I wouldn't be able to tell), but in that case down vote, don't flag.

Comment: This resolved my issue. Just setting height:1%; does the trick, in fact having a height:30px caused the issue.

Comment: When we inspected elements on our site, we noticed that `box-sizing` was set to `border-box`.  When this property was set it was causing the `height` to be interpreted as `0px`.  Changing either of those worked for us.

Comment: I managed to solve the issue by decreasing the padding and increasing the height.

Answer (score 4):

I found out the `box-sizing: border-box;` did not work, so I changed it to `content-box`:

```
@media screen and (-ms-high-contrast: active), screen and (-ms-high-contrast: none) {
   /* IE10+ specific style */
   input:not([type="select"]),
   input:not([type="submit"]) {
     padding: 15px 20px;
     box-sizing: content-box;
     line-height: normal;
     width: auto;
     height: 15px;
     display: inline-block;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

For me looks like >= IE8 has a problem with box-sizing css property.. it seems to be hiding text it cant fit.. I had to adjust my padding and font-size for IE to fix this issue. Not sure if this is the same issue you have.. but worth a shot.

Comment: Removing `border-box` property works for me. But damn IE!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and found out that it was the setting of my CSS framework (Foundation) that put a height of 2.4375rem to all inputs... You need to override that! With something like

```
[type=color],
[type=date],
[type=datetime-local],
[type=datetime],
[type=email],
[type=month],
[type=number],
[type=password],
[type=search],
[type=tel],
[type=text],
[type=time],
[type=url],
[type=week],
textarea {
    height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because Internet Explorer can't understand a CSS value of VW or VH for a font size. Just change your units for text boxes back to pixels (PX) and the problem goes away.